# Edit Joomla K2 frontend template

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I'm supporting a website running on Joomla 2.5.14 with K2, and I need to make the product page change based on values entered into custom fields in the CMS. I don't work with Joomla regularly, and can't find where I would change the code that runs the page. Here's an example product page: http://exmweb.com/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=147:es-standard-door&Itemid=533&lang=en

Where in Joomla's file system would I find the PHP and HTML that control the dropdown menus on this page?

Thanks,

Luke

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. For any fellow Joomla K2 newbies, you find template overrides for K2 in /templates/[template_folder_name]/html/com_k2/[override_template_name].

Comment: For Joomla 3.x this location is: `/components/com_k2/[override_template_name]`

Comment: @lukenjohnson could you please post a answer to your question and select it as accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any fellow Joomla 2.5 K2 newbies, you find template overrides for K2 in /templates/[template_folder_name]/html/com_k2/[override_template_name].